# Using an ajax reload with a Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am making a Wordpress plugin that provides updates in the widget section of the page - everything works fine.  The one thing that doesn't is the ajax callback (using load with jquery).  It appears that Wordpress is blocking direct access to the php file that I am trying to load (it is in /wp-content/plugins/myplugin).

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not make a proxy script in the root of your site to get the output of that script by simply including it? e.g.:

```
<?php
include '/wp-content/plugins/myplugin.php';
?>
```

Comment: I imagine it would work, but I'd like to distribute it eventually and would prefer not having that as a requirement.  It may be the only way though.